# Error in creating temp files on mac os

Tags: c++, c, file-io, osx-snow-leopard

Om mac OS 10.6.7, I am creating some files in the temp directory. After a while I start getting failure in open syscall and error returned is 24 which means disk full. I checked the disk space and still 80GB is available. Are there any restrictions or special quota on temporary directory? I used following flags to open the file:
open(path, O_RDWR | O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR)

The RAM usage is fairly high during this point, (around 90%), but I dont think it should affect the file open especially when it says disk full as the returned error.

Did anyone face such a situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Error 24 is EMFILE meaning too many open files.

Comment: Oh yes! thanks. I did not look at the error description properly.

Answer (score 0):

this error code 24 is for `EMFILE`

which indicates that maximum files are already open by current process so now more files can not be opened. So changes some how the maximum limit of opened file per process in your system or try to close files after usages if possible then

if i remember then maximum files open at a time in one process is 20 by default.

Comment: Today's systems have higher values (mine says 1024). Check it with "ulimit -n".